# Git Ignoring funny ref

Tags: git

I have a repo that I've cloned locally using `git clone --bare`

When doing a `git pull` or a `git fetch`, I receive the following error on all the branches, here's the prod branch for example:

`error: * Ignoring funny ref 'refs/remotes/origin//production' locally`

I imagine it's the double slashes that are messing it up, but I'm not sure. How would I be able to fix this so that the path is not malformed locally, and I don't have to run off to my principal and argue with them about our git practices?

Comment: According to the source code the message "ignoring funny ref" comes from [`check_refname_format`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/142430338477d9d1bb25be66267225fb58498d92/remote.c#L1954) which [performs several tests](https://github.com/git/git/blob/49f38e2de47a401fc2b0f4cce38e9f07fb63df48/refs.c), and double-slashes is one of them.

Comment: What is the question? "Where does it come from?", "How to fix it?", something else?

Comment: @knittl my apologies, I have amended my question. Essentially yes, without changing the remote, how can I pull these remote branches and work on them?

Comment: Side question: how did you (or whoever) manage to create the bogus branch name in the first place? :-)

Comment: @torek what drives me crazy about this is it only seems to be my machine that's screaming about this issue. I'm working with my job currently to get a new one, I'm not sure if it's because I got issued an M1 mac (there's been other odd behavior as well) or not, but the same actions on my personal linux laptop work totally fine.

Comment: Probably your M1-mac Git version is newest and someone tightened some ref validity check recently. The ongoing work to have a new true-ref-database back end for ref names has led to a lot of cleanup in the ref management code...

Answer (score 1):

Try to fetch the ref explicitly:

```
git fetch origin +refs/heads//production:refs/remotes/origin/funny-production
```

Or add it to your `.git/config` file for the "origin" remote:

```
[remote "origin"]
url = …
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
fetch = +refs/heads//production:refs/remotes/origin/funny-production
```